# OpenSSH, как удалить ключи и создать один новый

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, ssh, openssh

Создал несколько ключей, использовал последний для публичной части (и без пароля). Но пароль таки спрашивает. В чем оплошность?

Comment: уточните пожалуйста как Вы создавали ключи?

Comment: `ssh-keygen`, затем ввел после `Enter file in which to save the key`: `ssh`, появились ключи с этим именем (это в последний раз).

Comment: Сначала `rm -r ~/.ssh` (вся папка со всеми ключами канет в Лету), а потом `ssh-keygen -v -b 4096 -t rsa -C 'Мой суперсекурный ключ'`. И без пароля. Теперь спрашивает?